# Virtual Device Manager won't open when new flutter project starts

Tags: flutter, android-studio

After install android studio on new device i got one annoying issul.
Virtual Device Manager won't open by button on pannel untill i set "Android" module in "project stucture".
And every time I start new flutter project i should add this module.

I would like it to be preseted.
Is this possible? and where can i set it?

hope for your help

Comment: that's the bug in bumblebee.... wait for an update :-) .. but there is an open issue ... the developers are informed https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5917

Comment: @Raegtime oh... hope they fix it soon, thanks for informing